# In Java, how can I HttpPost only the contents of a protocol buffer?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've tried using a ByteArrayEntity, as below, but this sends extra bytes that aren't in the protocol buffer itself. Is there an Entity which just POSTs the contents?

```
        byte [] info;

        ... [info initialized] ...

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myurl");
        ByteArrayEntity reqEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(info);

        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true);
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Are you writing/parsing your protobuf with or without the "Delimited" methods?

Comment: I'm using strings and repeated elements - but does ByteArrayEntity care about the contents of the byte []?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is disappointingly banal: the extra bytes were added by the call to setChunked(true). Removing the call results in only the bytes in "info" getting sent.